# Libgdx assetmanager, game quit when load .otf font

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx

i use the libgdx assetmanager to load assets. it's sound good when only load the images and sounds/musics. but i've got the problems when load the .otf font. the game quit, while assetmanager is in progress.

here's the code:
Java file AssetsManager.java

```
assetManager = new AssetManager();

// set the loaders for the generator and the fonts themselves
FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
assetManager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
assetManager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".otf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

// load to fonts via the generator (implicitely done by the FreetypeFontLoader).
// Note: you MUST specify a FreetypeFontGenerator defining the ttf font file name and the size
// of the font to be generated. The names of the fonts are arbitrary and are not pointing
// to a file on disk!
FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter freeTypeFontLoaderParameterScore = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
freeTypeFontLoaderParameterScore.fontFileName = Constants.FONT_DEFAULT;
freeTypeFontLoaderParameterScore.fontParameters.size = Constants.XLG_FONT_SIZE;
assetManager.load("defaultScore.otf", BitmapFont.class, freeTypeFontLoaderParameterScore);

FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter freeTypeFontLoaderParameterScoreShadow = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
freeTypeFontLoaderParameterScoreShadow.fontFileName = Constants.FONT_DEFAULT;
freeTypeFontLoaderParameterScoreShadow.fontParameters.size = Constants.XLG_FONT_SIZE;
assetManager.load("defaultScoreShadow.otf", BitmapFont.class, freeTypeFontLoaderParameterScoreShadow);

FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter freeTypeFontLoaderParameterElapsedTime = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
freeTypeFontLoaderParameterElapsedTime.fontFileName = Constants.FONT_DEFAULT;
freeTypeFontLoaderParameterElapsedTime.fontParameters.size = Constants.MD_FONT_SIZE;
assetManager.load("defaultElapsedTime.otf", BitmapFont.class, freeTypeFontLoaderParameterElapsedTime);

FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter freeTypeFontLoaderParameterElapsedTimeShadow = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
freeTypeFontLoaderParameterElapsedTimeShadow.fontFileName = Constants.FONT_DEFAULT;
freeTypeFontLoaderParameterElapsedTimeShadow.fontParameters.size = Constants.MD_FONT_SIZE;
assetManager.load("defaultElapsedTimeShadow.otf", BitmapFont.class, freeTypeFontLoaderParameterElapsedTimeShadow);
```

Mygame.java

```
@Override
public void create () {
    AssetsManager.getInstance().loadAssets();
    setScreen(new SplashScreen());
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    AssetsManager.getInstance().dispose();
    AudioManager.dispose();
    Gdx.app.log("STATUS", "DISPOSING");
}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();
    if (finishedLoadingSplash == false){
        if (AssetsManager.getInstance().update()){
            finishedLoadingSplash = true;
            AudioManager.getInstance().init();
            setScreen(new GameScreen());
        }
    }
}
```

in the code above, assetmanager load 4 bitmapfont from .otf file.
while assetmanager is in progress, the game quit suddenly.

but if i deleting some code, so the assetmanager just load 1 or 2 bitmapfont or if i change the font(the font file size is 136kb and i change the font with under 40kb), the game is good not quit suddenly. did i make mistake? thanks

Comment: any error in the logcat??

Comment: i think no. i just got "com.mygame.test.android (10481) [DEAD]" in the android monitor, and no "force close" message in the device.

Comment: You should see a stacktrace in crash log. Please use logat without any specific parameter. If you trace logcat using basic "adb logcat" command you will see a stacktrace.